# IE 11 CSS Inches NOT Working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing, width

Very simple, I've created a report, and use printThis.js JQuery plugin, which works perfectly on all browsers and all platforms, except when I send the report via IE, the CSS inch measurements, which should be inches regardless of browser, all the sudden are 2/3 of their normal size. All browsers are set to LETTER size 8.5 x 11, so the page setups are identical.

On Firefox, Chrome, Safari, 1 inch is 1 inch. On IE, 1 inch is .75in.

I've searched all over the web, but given that IE has metric tons of problems associated with CSS, the results are impossible to isolate to my issue. I'm sure there are answers out there, but I can't find them amid all the legacy issues with this pile of steaming browser.

Appreciate any help.

Question: How do you make 1.0in in CSS 1.0in in IE printing?

Comment: If its only for `IE` you can use `media` hacks particular to `IE` and override  your properties.

Comment: I've been hacking at the raw values of width, and the print job goes absolutely out of its mind. All I have some div tags inside a wrapper. I'm setting the @page size, and a content div tag's width to 8in x 10in and IE freaks out and prints everything left justified. Remove those tags and the report comes out right, just 75% (roughly) of the original dimensions.